# Почему в joomla на главной странице выводятся только те модули, которые установлены для отображения на всех страницах?

Tags: joomla

Оно отображает только те модули где menuid =0 то есть "на всех страницах". Я же хочу установить модуль только на главной

Comment: Необходимо многое уточнить, какая версия, какой шаблон, какие настройки модулей и т.д. Вариантов решения проблемы может быть масса.

Comment: Например та позиция в которой вы пытаетесь выводить модули, шаблоном отображается только на главной.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, та позиция отображается везде, так как еси я ставлю показывать на всех страницах, у меня модуль на всех страницах. Когда показываю на главной только, его нет нигде

Comment: Может быть у вас путаница с "меню главная" и "алиасом меню главная", это иногда дает как раз такой эффект, что вы думаете что на главной а на самом деле вы не на главной а на алиасе главной и происходит глюк, я такое встречал.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, Какой алиас? Есть пункт меню "Главная" к нему прикреплен модуль, он не отображается. У меня нет алиасов Как проверить?

Comment: Я мог бы помочь разобраться, но тут видимо надо по скайпу с показом экрана и голосом, так в слепую однако... В моем профиле есть сайт, там есть мои контакты, стучите если что.